# JBoss + Apache via ModJK Documentation

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, jboss

I'm trying to serve my application's content on JBoss through Apache. Load balancing is not necessary yet.

I've been trying to follow [this guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss) on JBoss' wiki but it seems more complicated than what I'm looking to do, since I'm not trying to get loadbalance to work. I also found [this other example](http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2008/04/13/12-deploying-a-j2ee-application-behind-an-apache-server-in-a-production-environment), but I haven't been able to make this work.

Several trial and error hasn't helped getting too far. Can you recommend any good conceptual tutorials for doing this? These tutorials I've found kind of explain what to do, but don't go too deep into what you are doing. Not only do I want to get this to work, but also learn what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357035/apache-jboss-use-port-80-at-the-same-time/1357694#1357694)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's JK documentation [for the impatient](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html) is a good place to start.  That, and the RedHat doc on [optimizing mod_jk](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-15866) configs, and the [lbconfig appengine ... er, app](http://lbconfig.appspot.com/) are essential.

Interesting, none of those are listed in the resources page of the wiki page you found.  Let's see if I can add them...

Answer (score 1):

Given a Red Hat/CentOS server, just replace 'Tomcat' with 'JBoss' and here's the short & sweet version:

[How can I set use mod_proxy_ajp with Apache and Tomcat?](https://serverfault.com/questions/106254/how-can-i-set-use-mod-proxy-ajp-with-apache-and-tomcat/106290#106290)